# Capture user input on HTML canvas/Javascript and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle in HTML5 canvas based on user input.  I am also trying to do the opposite.  If a user draws a rectangle in the canvas, the width and height values are dropped into the form.  Please see my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hbrennan72/FyTx5/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rect = {};
//var drag = false;

    function getarea() 
     {      
            var wid = document.getElementById("wid").value;
            var hgt = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
            var area = wid * hgt;
            var perim = wid * 2 + hgt * 2;

             if (wid =="") {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "The value for the width is blank.";
                    document.getElementById('wid').focus();
             }

             else if (hgt == "") {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "The value for the height is blank.";
                    document.getElementById("hgt").focus();
             }

            else if (isNaN (wid)) {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "Please enter a numeric value for the width.";
                    document.getElementById('wid').focus();
            }

            else if (isNaN (hgt)) {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "Please enter a numeric value for the height.";
                    document.getElementById("hgt").focus();
            }

            else if (wid <= 0) {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "The width is less than or equal to zero.";
                    document.getElementById('wid').focus();
            }

            else if (hgt <= 0) {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "The height is less than or equal to zero.";
                    document.getElementById("hgt").focus();
            }

            else if (wid > 500) {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "The width is greater than 500.";
                    document.getElementById('wid').focus();
            }

            else if (hgt > 500) {
                    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "The height is greater than 500.";
                    document.getElementById("hgt").focus();
            }

            else {
                window.document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = area;
                window.document.getElementById("perim").innerHTML = perim;
                document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = "Please see results listed above.";
           }

    }



    function updateform (){
        "use strict"
        var wid = document.getElementById("wid").value;
        var hgt = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
        var area = wid * hgt;

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2D");
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillRect(0,0, rect.wid, rect.hgt);
        context.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; //red color
        draw();
    }

    function mouseDown(e) 
    {
      rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      canvas.style.cursor="crosshair";
      drag = true;
    }

    function mouseUp () {
        drag = false;
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
      if (drag) {
        rect.wid = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.hgt = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        draw();
      }
    }

    function init() {
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
    }

    init();

    function drawform() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2D");
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillRect(0,0, rect.wid, rect.hgt);
        context.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; //red color

    }

    function draw (){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.wid, rect.hgt);
        context.fillStyle = "#378E37"; //green color    
    }

    draw();
```

Comment: And what's the problem you have?

Comment: [This is what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/FyTx5/1/)

Comment: @RahilWazir I think the questioner wants it to work the opposite way also.  After dragging to create a new rect on canvas then they want the form to reflect the width/height of the dragged rect ;-)

Comment: Yes, that is part of it!  Other than adding the rect.wid=wid/rect.hgt=hgt, what else changed?

Comment: Correct markE.  That is the part I am scratching my head on.  After the object has been painted on the canvas, capturing those values and placing them in the wid & hgt inputs on the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do it in this way.It is working fine.The code is

```
$("#smt").click(function(){
        var canvasel=' <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>'
        $("#canvas").append(canvasel)
        var w=$("#wid").val();
        var h=$("#hgt").val();
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.rect(20,20,w,h);
        ctx.stroke();

    })

$("#clr").click(function(){
    $("#canvas").empty();
    $("#wid").val('');
    $("#hgt").val('');

})

initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas'));



function initDraw(canvas) {
    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
        if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
            mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
            mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
            mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    };

    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
    };
    var element = null;

    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        setMousePosition();
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
            element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
            element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
            element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        }
    }

    canvas.onclick = function (e) {
        if (element !== null) {
            element = null;
            canvas.style.cursor = "default";
            console.log("finsihed.");
            var width=$(".rectangle").width();
            var height=$(".rectangle").height();

            $("#wid").val(width);
            $("#hgt").val(height)
        } else {
            console.log("begun.");
            mouse.startX = mouse.x;
            mouse.startY = mouse.y;
            element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle'
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            canvas.appendChild(element)
            canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
        }
    }
}
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/f3mBM/)

NOTE:Its not working in Mozilla. I am trying to fix it.Check in Chrome

Comment: if you have something problem in my above above code.Just ask